# App crahing when Button declared outside onCreate method

Tags: android

The following code crashes the app

```
public class SharedPreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSave); //**ERROR**

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_preferences);
}
```

Whereas the following code works fine

```
 public class SharedPreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_preferences);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);//**REPLACED BUTTON DECLARATION**
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `Why is this happening?` because you can't declare stuff like that outside on create

Comment: View has not been initalised. Please google your question before asking

Comment: What i wanted to do is use Button outside of onCreate() method.
Found out that First I need to declare button outside method and initialize using oncreate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a reference to your button `globally` then you should declare it outside then initialize it in `onCreate`

```
Button b1; //declare the button variable

public class SharedPreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_preferences);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave); //initialize on creation
}
```

You should read more into the basics of `Java` when learning `Android`

Comment: Button button; //declare the button variable

public class SharedPreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_preferences);

   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave); //initialize on creation
}